# In simple English what is meant by "tagging", "triggering", "selection criteria" and "reconstructed events/particles/masses" in particle physics?

Tags: particle-physics, terminology, computational-physics, higgs, accelerator-physics

I am currently reading the original Higgs boson discovery paper, "Observation of a new boson at a mass of $125$ GeV with the CMS experiment at the LHC", HIG-12-028, which can be found towards the bottom of [this webpage](http://cms-results.web.cern.ch/cms-results/public-results/publications/HIG/HIG.html) on [the Cern website](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/CMSPublic/PhysicsResultsHIG) published on 31 July 2012.

I'm finding it very hard to understand and appreciate the importance of this paper due to the extreme amount of technical jargon used in that paper. So I am going to ask about the $4$ technical terms that come up the most often in that paper. I will use a color code here where $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ is the word I'm trying to understand (mentioned in the title of this post) and $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ for other words used within the same quote that I don't understand either:

1. **Tagging**

> To suppress the top-quark background, a “top $\color{blue}{\text{tagging}}$” technique based on soft-muon and bjet $\color{blue}{\text{tagging}}$ is applied. The first method is designed to $\color{red}{\text{veto}}$ events containing muons from b jets coming from decays of top quarks. The second method uses a b-jet $\color{blue}{\text{tagging}}$ algorithm, which looks within jets for tracks with large $\color{red}{\text{impact parameters}}$.

The passage above can be found on page 18, and has just introduced two other words which I don't understand either, I looked at [this Wikipedia page for "veto"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_anticoincidence), but still don't understand its meaning. Moreover, what is meant by "$\color{red}{\text{impact parameters}}$" in this context?

2. **Triggering**

> The muon system consists of four stations in the barrel and endcaps, designed to ensure robust $\color{blue}{\text{triggering}}$ and detection of muons over a large angular range.

The above passage is found on page 5 (amongst other places).

3. **Selection criteria**

> Additional $\color{blue}{\text{selection criteria}}$ are applied to each event to remove spurious features originating from isolated noise patterns in certain HCAL regions, and from anomalous signals caused by particles depositing energy in the silicon avalanche photodiodes used in the ECAL barrel region.

The above passage is also be found on page 5 (towards the bottom).

4. **Event/particle/mass reconstruction**

> The CMS “particle-flow” event description algorithm [35,36] is used to $\color{blue}{\text{reconstruct}}$ and identify each single particle with an optimized combination of all subdetector information. In this process, the identification of the particle (photon, electron, muon, charged hadron, neutral hadron) plays an important role in the determination of the particle momentum. The $\color{blue}{\text{reconstructed particles}}$ are henceforth referred to as objects.

The above passage is also found at the bottom of page 5 and is just below the previous quote on "selection criteria".

---

I know this is a lot of questions for one post, but I tried my best to narrow it down to the 4 words that come up the most often. If I asked for the meaning of each and every word that I don't understand then I would need to make about 50 posts.

I would just like to mention that I have tried very hard to search for definitions of these words (in the post title), but each time I do so I get yet more jargon/terminology that I don't understand.

The first word ("tagging") I was asking about, actually has an answer [here on this site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13447/what-does-tagging-mean-in-experimental-high-energy-physics), but, I'm still a little confused even after reading that answer as it does not actually address *how* tagging is accomplished.

So to summarize, can someone please explain in layman's terms (where possible) what is meant by those 4 words in the title of this post?

Comment: I know you have tried to narrow this down, but really each of your four terms is complex enough to warrant a standalone question. Consider asking them serially, rather than four separate questions at once. Also, the technical term “impact parameter” is a compound noun.

Comment: You need to realise that these articles are targeted towards a specialised audience, most of whom, but not necessarily all of them, are familiar with these concepts. Also this 30 or so page article summarises  work by hundreds, if not thousands. So the text must be very concise. It is quite unreasonable to expect to understand the details of such an article for a lay person. And most probably many co-authors of this article don't even understand all the details....

Comment: tagging = data analysis that selects that kind of event. triggering = making the electronics actually record a signal. Selection criteria = not jargon but exactly what it says, some requirement that picks a particular type of events from a large data set (i.e. similar to tagging) Reconstruction = estimate that quantity based on the measured data.

Comment: Usually, a paper announcing a major result is not the best place to learn about the methods. There will be a series of background papers (and, for key methods in established fields like particle physics, digestible versions of those papers at different levels in the form of reviews, textbooks, lectures, blog posts, and popular science articles) that explain the methods. The discovery paper usually just gives the main results, assuming the methods are understood by the reader. [This](https://www.lhc-closer.es/taking_a_closer_look_at_lhc/0.lhc_data_analysis) looks like a good starting point.

Comment: [This page](http://lhc-closer.es/taking_a_closer_look_at_lhc/0.lhc_trigger) also is relevant. (Between the two links there is some explanation about triggering, selection criteria, and event reconstruction).

Comment: I think some context will help. What they get from the detector is something like a bunch of blips (events) from various collision products hitting various subdetectors arranged around the collision site, and a bunch of blips that are background noise. They then have to process this data to *reconstruct* (infer) what actually happened, and compare with theoretical predictions, which are calculated via running simulations. E.g. a reconstructed particle is one inferred from the detector data, a MC (Monte Carlo) particle is the simulated equivalent. 1/2

Comment: Tagging, i think, means categorizing some subset of data - identifying what it represents in terms of the processes that are expected to happen in there; this is (if I'm not mistaken) accomplished via AI (machine learning) - e.g., by training a neural network on simulated data, then running it on real data. They also reject ("cut") a bunch of data based on various criteria, to improve signal/noise ratio - which is what event selection is about. Triggering seems to be a real-time filtering system (embedded in the detector?) that reduces the amount of recorded data for offline analysis. 2/2